# is it possible to connect to cloudsql in golang?

Tags: go, google-cloud-sql

the google documentation seems to hint that the app engine go SDK should support using cloudsql, but from [this snippet of code](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-go/source/browse/appengine/cloudsql/cloudsql_dev.go), it looks like it's not yet supported.

is there a newer version of the SDK that does allow you to interface with cloudsql?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud SQL works with the latest SDK. The online docs haven't been updated. Pick a MySQL driver of your choosing that can work with appengine/cloudsql package and the databse/sql package will work. Some of the working drivers : mymysql https://github.com/ziutek/mymysql or go-sql-driver : https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql

Comment: have you tried this yourself and gotten it to work? because I've tried both of those drivers and I always get the error "cloudsql: not supported in dev yet", which makes sense when you look at the code I linked to in my question.

Comment: Post your code here so we can a take a look. I haven't tried MySQL with Go as I use MongoDB mostly.